# android tint animation doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, tint

I have custom `ImageView` which should animate its content after loading from solid background color to image with `setColorFilter`:

```
private void _animate() {
    int bgColor= ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.iconPlaceholderBg);
    int transparent=ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),android.R.color.transparent);
    ValueAnimator bgAnim= ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(),bgColor,transparent);
    bgAnim.setDuration(5000);
    //bgAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    bgAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            //Log.d("anim",animation.getAnimatedFraction()+"")
            //Image.this.clearColorFilter();
            Image.this.setColorFilter((int)animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    bgAnim.start();
}
```

Animation itself runs as expexted (5 seconds long).However content appears immediately in the final position(without color transformation).I've tried different `PorterDuff.Mode` modes but looks like none of them do things right.
Are there any workarounds to get desired effect?

Comment: i assume `animation.getAnimatedValue()` returns a correct value for each animation frame?

Comment: yeah the problem is my background color has almost 0 alpha.When I change it to solid opaque color.It started to work.Looks like I can't get this effect with tint tranformation.

Comment: btw this one line just works ok: `ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv); ObjectAnimator.ofObject(iv, "colorFilter", new ArgbEvaluator(), 0, 0xaa0000ff).setDuration(500).start();`

Comment: nope same effect - no animation at all
`ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "colorFilter", new ArgbEvaluator(), bgColor, transparent).setDuration(5000).start();`
bg color is `#195C3B52`.Anyway I found acceptable workaround:see below.

Comment: so what starting alpha does not work? 0xff works but 0x19 doesnt? no, 0x19 is simply to small to see any difference, if you want to ignore your alpha value then make a custom `ArgbEvaluator` class and override its `evaluate` method

Comment: I want my image view to have solid background color at start, then it smoothly fades out and my image fades in.Your example doesn't do that.

Comment: so exchange `0, 0xaa0000ff` with `0xff0000ff, 0`

Comment: if you see my previous comment, you notice I've already done this:
`ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "colorFilter", new ArgbEvaluator(), bgColor, transparent).setDuration(5000).start();`

Comment: so what does not work with it?

Comment: >same effect - no animation at all

Comment: yes, trhere is 5 second animation from solid blue to transparent: `ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
                ObjectAnimator.ofObject(iv, "colorFilter", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.BLUE, 0).setDuration(5000).start();
`

Comment: it works with opaque colors, but with trasparency the effect is different.

Comment: so either pass a custom `ArgbEvaluator` object or simply make the first color completely opaque: `origColor | 0xff000000`, or use a `TransitionDrawable`: *"An extension of LayerDrawables that is intended to cross-fade between the first and second layer"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my background color which has tranparency.For some reason `setColorFilter` works not exactly as you expect with trasparent colors.I've managed to get desired behaviour with following workaround:

```
Image.this.getDrawable().setAlpha((int) (animation.getAnimatedFraction()*255));
```